How to express the angle between altitudes of parallelogram to its adjacent sides in terms of angles of this parallelogram?
Consider parallelogram $ABCD$ ($AB\parallel CD$, $BC\parallel AD$) as shown:

Pick a pair of its opposite vertices, say $B$ and $D$:

From these vertices, construct altitudes to the adjacent sides of this parallelogram:

From vertex $B$ construct an altitude $BH_1$ to side $AD$.
From vertex $D$ construct altitude $DH_2$ to side $AB$.

Two lines containing these altitudes will always intersect as they are perpendicular to two intersecting sides of parallelogram.

Let $H$ be such intersection point.

Let $\angle DHH_1$ be the smaller angle between $BH_1$ and $DH_2$.

How to express such angle in terms of interior angles of parallelogram $ABCD$?
It is evident from the drawing that this angle is equal to the acute angle of this parallelogram, but I would like a rigorous proof of that. I wonder if it always works.

$\angle HDH_1 = 90^\circ -\angle A$, $\angle DHH_1 = 90^\circ -\angle HDH_1$.

$\angle DHH_1+\angle H_1HH_2=180^\circ$, and in quadrilateral $AH_1HH_2$ we have $\angle A+\angle AH_1H+\angle H_1HH_2+\angle AH_2H=360^\circ$, hence $\angle A+\angle H_1HH_2=180^\circ$. Therefore, $\angle DHH_1=\angle A$.

The comment/answers from peterwhy and Feng are immediate paths, almost like visual reflexes:

$\triangle{ABH_1}$ divides into similar triangles
$AH_1HH_2$ is cyclic

Consider too that a parallelogram contains only two angles:

$90-\alpha$
$90+\alpha$

A perpendicular meeting those angles can only form:

complement of (acute) $90-\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$
removal of $90$ from (obtuse) $90+\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$

So the angle divided out by the altitude at vertex $D$ must be $\alpha$, and the angle marked in the diagram must be $90-\alpha$, which is the original angle at $A$.
